# viewWillAppear not called apparently due to my view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift, viewwillappear, application-lifecycle, view-hierarchy

This appears to be a well documented problem, yet the solutions online have not worked.
Here's just a sample list of posts that failed to provide me with a working answer:

- [ViewWillAppear not executing code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32725223/viewwillappear-not-executing-code)
- [viewWillAppear not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34350565/viewwillappear-not-getting-called)
- [viewWillAppear not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4673294/viewwillappear-not-called)
- [UINavigationController Inheritance, ViewWillAppear not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772656/uinavigationcontroller-inheritance-viewwillappear-not-called)
- [viewWillAppear not called after popToViewController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268259/viewwillappear-not-called-after-poptoviewcontroller)
- [iPhone viewWillAppear not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131062/iphone-viewwillappear-not-firing)

I have gleaned that my problem with viewWillAppear not getting called has to do with my view hierarchy. I am using a tab controller that is not the highest part of the view hierarchy. One of the tab controller's view controllers is a root view controller to a navigation controller. That's where I am trying to get a working viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear. Here's what I tried that has not worked. Within the tab controller I added this code:

```
let nav2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: locationsVC)
nav2.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
//...//
viewControllers = [ nav1, nav2, nav3, nav4 ]

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    for vc in self.children {
         vc.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

In the scene delegate, this is my code:

```
guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
self.window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
let rootVC = NewOrExistingViewController()
rootVC.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
let rootNC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootVC)
rootNC.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
rootNC.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
self.window?.rootViewController = rootNC
let tbc = TabBarViewController()
tbc.selectedIndex = 0
tbc.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)
rootVC.add(asChildViewController: tbc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `rootVC.add(asChildViewController: tbc)` before `rootVC.beginAppearanceTransition(true, animated: false)`.

All your child VCs need to already be children of the parent before you call `func beginAppearanceTransition(_: animated:)`